# Complement of Normal subgroups and free groups

Tags: group-theory

Does every normal subgroup has complement in free groups? What about free abelian groups i.e. Is free abelian gorup complemented group?

**Definition**: If there exist a subgroup K such that HK = G and H ∩ K = {e}, then K is called complement of H. Here e is identity of G

Comment: What do you mean by the complement of a normal subgroup? In which sense?

Comment: ok. What is the complement of $2\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Malkoun okay I got it. complement of 2Z doesn't exist because any other subgroup intersect it.

Comment: I am glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

I know that if |G|=p^n where p is a prime number and G is a ableian group and assume H«G that H is cyclic with maximal order in G then H is complement in G we can prove this with sylow's theorms

Comment: I don't think I see how this is relevant to the OP's question. Is there some connection?